# Unable to import pypi module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pypi

**I am unable to import the `pypi` module (https://pypi.org/project/pypi/) into one of my python scripts.**

I added the below line to my script to see which paths it's trying to get modules from:

`print(sys.path)`

Which shows the following:

```
`'/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/', '/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages']
```

I have used `pip` to force the installation into those specific folders:

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade --target=/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ pypi
sudo pip3 install --upgrade --target=/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages pypi
```

In both cases the installation is successful:

```
Collecting pypi
Installing collected packages: pypi
Successfully installed pypi-2.1
```

If I go check those folders, the package is there:

```
ls -lh /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages | grep pypi
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Apr 25 11:03 pypi-2.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Apr 25 10:49 pypi-2.1-py3.5.egg-info
```

If I manually install the package I get something similar:

- https://pypi.org/project/pypi/#files
- Downloaded & Extracted `pypi-2.1.tar.gz`
- Then ran setup

```
python3.5 ./setup.py install
running install
running build
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pypi-2.1.egg-info
```

**Here is my script**:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
import pypi
```

**And the error I get:**

```
$ python3.5 myscrypt.py
[..., '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages','/usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages']
import pypi
ImportError: No module named 'pypi'
```

**What am I missing to import `pypi`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no importable modules or packages in the `pypi` package. The package was created to reserve the name so that evil hackers don't publish packages with this name.

What are really trying to install?

Comment: I want to look for info on python packages: **1)** scan `.py` files for `import` statements  to identify imported modules **2)** Retrieve the pypi package info (website/github URLs **3)** Repeat those steps on hundreds of data-science related projects to build an inventory of most used packages, website URLs to go check them out etc.. A sort of package research/monitoring tool. As I came across this https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/3354 which showed `pypi.search({'name': query, 'summary': query}, 'or')` so I thought `pypi` was a package. But I'm open to other solutions if you have

Comment: [The previous line](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/a421676ec4d9bcd3f8e243e8abf55b0f900a0f66/pip/commands/search.py#L59) shows that `pypi` there is an XML-RPC client that connects to `pypi.org`.

Comment: So I guess they use some sort of XML API to read the `pypi` database and fetch info?

Comment: Ended up using their JSON API (https://warehouse.readthedocs.io/api-reference/json/), very easy to consume with https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/